# Loosing Focus While Typing On Custom Input Field React-Final-Form-Arrays

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I'm using custom component to show the text input field nothing fancy just the basic component

```
const CustomTextField = ({ ...rest }) => {
  return <input {...rest} />;
};
```

When I'm trying to using this component inside react-final-form-array for some reason I'm losing focus when typing on the input field, I guess it's because of the re-rendering.

```
<Field
    name={`${name}.lastName`}
    component={({ input, meta, ...rest }) => {
      return (
        <CustomTextField {...input} type="text" {...rest} />
      );
    }}
    placeholder="Last Name"
  />
```

here is the link to the full code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-arrays-forked-gguhd?file=/index.js:1961-2313)

As you can see the "First Name" works fine but the "Last Name" losing focus while typing.

How can I fix this issue, any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
const CustomTextField = (props) => {
  return <input {...props.input} />;
};
```

and

```
<Field 
   name={`${name}.lastName`} 
   component={CustomTextField}
   placeholder="Last Name"
/>
```

Comment: I didn't see that, if your answer works that great for OP